# Why can't we upvote comments on nominations?

Tags: discussion, comment, election

> Why can't we upvote comments on nominations?

Normally a user can vote on a comment to indicate that they agree with the sentiment it contains; this saves them from having to post a similar comment. Using the same system during the nomination stage of an election would allow users to indicate that they share the concern previously raised by another user, or to add to the support shown by another user.

**Added Later:** Arthur Fischer's comment on Daniel Fischer's nomination appears to have been upvoted, but I still can't upvote any of the comments.

Comment: "I vote for you." comments could turn the thing into a pseudo-election.

Comment: And quite a few of those have been deleted already.

Comment: I do remember this was possible before.

Comment: @Asaf yes it was possible. But it is now impossible *by design.* But this is not the first complaint I heard related to it, so maybe it will be changed back.

Comment: @quid: I hope it will. I would like to complain about my nomination, when Shog [will drop the anvil on my head](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17667/it-is-ridiculous-that-people-like-me-can-nominate#comment65989_17668), and I would like everyone to vote those comments!

Comment: [Related on Meta.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245030/cannot-upvote-comments-under-an-election-nomination)

Comment: On your added: likely a bug or hack, chances are SE only took away the interface to vote, and did not actually block it.

Comment: Guessed right, see http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19057631#19057631

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245124/can-too-upvote-comments-under-an-election-nomination for the bugreport

Comment: There I thought for a moment I missed an upcoming election...

Comment: The functionality to upvote comments under the nomination posts has been (re-)added with the recent revamping of the election UI. Relevant Meta SE post: [Moderator Elections functionality: voting UI, commenting and flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361979).